# A formal word between 'frequently' and 'rarely'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, formality

Rarely:

> X rarely goes to Y

Frequently:

> X frequently goes to Y

What would be a word in between the two? A formal word for 'sometimes' maybe?

Context:

> Atheists sometimes appeal to Nietzsche's writing and use it to argue that he was against the idea of a God in general.

I need a formal word for sometimes. Frequently wouldn't be a good choice. Rarely wouldn't be either.

Comment: Knowing the context would be useful.

Comment: Just from the top of my head: seldom ,  infrequently , hardly, scarcely.

Comment: Can you please provide an example sentence?

Comment: @michael.hor257k edited

Comment: It sounds great if you drop the word altogether.  "Atheists appeal to ...."

Comment: What's wrong with *sometimes*? If you want an alternative to that word, have you looked up a thesaurus?

Comment: The question is not specific enough. The choice depends on how frequently or infrequently is meant.

Comment: It is specific enough hence I got answers including the one I'm looking for. Be light.

Comment: You didn't. There's no single answer.

Comment: I did and accepted the answer I got. On the contrary, you are here telling me that I'm wrong even though I provided an example and got the exact answer I was looking for. Scroll down and see yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, this depends on the context. In a formal setting I might say:

> X **periodically** goes to Y

> **[periodically](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/periodically)**
>
> 1 From time to time; occasionally.
> *‘I will periodically check on your progress’
>
> ‘the students received help from a friend only periodically’*

---

Now that you have updated the context, I would suggest:

> **[regularly](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/regularly)**
>
> 3. usually; ordinarily.

> Atheists **regularly** appeal to Nietzsche's writing and use it to argue that he was against the idea of a God in general.

---

If that seems too frequent for your needs, consider:

> **[from time to time](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+time+to+time)**
> Occasionally, once in a while. For example, *From time to time we play bridge with the Carters.*

or:

> **[at times](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+times)**
> sometimes; occasionally. *I feel quite sad at times. At times, I wish I had never come here.*

Comment: I would also suggest "occasionally" as a good choice.  After all, 3/4 of the definitions included in this answer offer it as a synonym!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's any more "formal" than *sometimes*
(but then, I don't regard *sometimes* as being
particularly informal to begin with),
but a *longer* word for *sometimes* is ***occasionally***:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occasionally):
>
>   : on occasion : now and then
>   //dines out
>   *occasionally*
>   //We
>   *occasionally*
>   see deer in the field.
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/occasionally):
>
>   At infrequent or irregular intervals; now and then.
>   *‘ very occasionally the condition can result in death’*
>   *‘ he met her occasionally for coffee’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=occasionally):
>
>   Now and then; from time to time.
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/occasionally):
>
>   from time to time
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/occasionally):
>
>   sometimes, but not frequently or regularly
>   *Simmer the sauce for ten minutes, stirring occasionally.*
>   *We go to the theater only very occasionally*
>   (=not often).